# C: Problems printf and scanf

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{

char name[90];
int age;
char letter;

printf("What is your name?\n");
scanf("%s", &name);

printf("How old are you?\n");
scanf("%d", &age);

printf("Where are you from?\n");
scanf("%s", &letter);

printf("Your name is %s, You are %d, You are from %s\n");
return 0;}
```

> Blockquote

İt is my code but it not working corretly.

Your name is å[N ⌂, You are 1323785094, You are from.-----        İ am gettin this.

Comment: You forgot to mention your variables in `printf()` call.

Comment: please don't confuse C and C++, they are two different languages.

Answer (score 4):

You have *three* major problems in your code:

1. `scanf("%s", &name);`

   The `%s` format specifier expects the argument to be a pointer to the first element of an array, and have the type `char *`. Since `name` is an array, `&name` is a pointer to the array itself and have the type `char (*)[90]`.

   To get a pointer to the first element, use `&name[0]`, or plain `name` as arrays naturally *decay* to pointers to their first element.
2. `scanf("%s", &letter);`

   As mentioned the `%s` format expects a pointer to the first element of an *array*. And it will add the string null-terminator character `'\0'` to the array after the characters it reads.

   That means even a single character will write *two* characters to the "array".

   For single characters use the `%c` format specifier. But note that you most likely need a leading space in the format, to skip any leading white-space (like the newline from the previous input):

   ```
   scanf(" %c", &letter);
   ```
3. `printf("Your name is %s, You are %d, You are from %s\n");`

   Here you tell `printf` to print some arguments, but you don't provide the actual arguments.

   Also note that as for `scanf` to print a single letter you need to use the `%c` format:

   ```
   printf("Your name is %s, You are %d, You are from %c\n", name, age, letter);
   ```

All three problems listed here will by themselves lead to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 1):

c++, array name is the array address, so you must use scanf("%s", name);

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{

char name[90];
int age;
char letter[90];

printf("What is your name?\n");
scanf("%s", name);

printf("How old are you?\n");
scanf("%d", &age);

printf("Where are you from?\n");
scanf("%s", letter);

printf("Your name is %s, You are %d, You are from %s\n", name, age, letter);
return 0;}
```

Comment: İ am new at coding. Ty

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work

```
printf("Your name is %s, You are %d, You are from %c\n", name, age, letter);
```